# Dojo Dgrid - canedit on filteringselect

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, dgrid

I have a dgrid assigned to a REST service with JSON. 
It works fine.

I have a filterselect in one of the columns. 
The filterselect is populated from another dojo store.

My question is, how can I disable the filterselect when it's value is for example 10?

I tried canEdit, but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
    Editor({
        label: 'Size', autoSave: true, field: 'picsubtype',
            canEdit: function(object, value) {
                return value != 10;
            },
            widgetArgs: {
                store: filesubtypeStore, maxHeight: 150, style: "height: 20px;"
            },
        }, FilteringSelect)
```

This code does not work...

Comment: If I add "click" at the end, I get the desired functionality, but then the filteringselect displays the values (1, 2, 3 and so on), and not the labels before I click on the select...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting up a `onChange` handler in the `widgetArgs`?
Something like:
`onChange: function(newValue) { if(newValue === 10) { this.set('disabled', true); } }`

But how would the widget get re-enabled?

Comment: I haven't tried `set('disabled', true)` yet. I will give it a go, and share the results with you. Thanks for your comment!